# How to convert add x days onto a var in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I have a file that contains many lines like the following :

```
0 D FakeSip          192.169.192.192                      jan/26/2022 17:10:31
```

I want to export the ip address, the date then add say 10 days onto the date, which will give me the expiry date. I have got the ip, and the inserted date no problem, but adding the 10 days on the date and exporting is proving a pain. Would be gratefull for some help please ?

```
cat FakeSip.txt|awk --posix '$4 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/ { print " IP Address "$4 " Date Identified "$5 " Expiration " (date -d  $5+10 days);}'
```

This is the output that is given with the above

```
IP Address 192.241.212.118 Date Identified jan/25/2022 Expiration 010
```

The Desired output would look like this :

```
IP Address 192.169.192.192 Date Identified jan/26/2022 Expiration Feb/05/2022
```

Comment: Welcome, you have to check that col 4 is an IP? could be something else?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions about text processing, please be sure to add a minimal reproducible example of the problem - i.e. (possible anonymized) example input, desired output, what you already tried, and in which way the output you got from your attempts deviates from the expectation. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Comment: Your data source is 25th Jan. Your example output is 26th Jan. That's neither the same as the input nor the input with an extra 10 days. And I can't see in your output where you want the input date +10 days. Please provide a few lines of input and the corresponding lines of desired output

Comment: Sorry, its because I was working on it last night..

Comment: When I run the `awk` command from the question with the input from the question I don't get the same actual output but `IP Address 192.169.192.192 Date Identified jan/26/2022 Expiration 010`. Did you run exactly the code shown in the question? Did you copy&paste it to the question or did you retype it?

Comment: @bodo - I re-tryped it However its still not the expected result ?

Comment: @Jez Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exact code you ran, the input you use and the actual output you get. On my system your code does not produce the output shown in the question, so there seems to be something wrong. Please fix your question. Otherwise we would try to fix errors that might have been introduced by typos in your code.

Comment: @Bodo  I have corrected the question -- thanks. .

Comment: @Jez Now the output no longer matches the input. Please check your question again and **copy&paste everything** from the system where you test your code.

Comment: Seems like there might be a couple of things going wrong here ... Firstly I don't think `date` is going to understand the format you're feeding it.  So I'd start by focusing on getting the `date` command to function as expected outside of `awk`.  Then I'd focus on capturing the output of a shell command that is being run inside `awk`.  This may help for the latter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960895/assigning-system-commands-output-to-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  LANG=C LC_ALL=C awk '
    $4 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/
      {
        dvar = $5;
        gsub("[^[:digit:][:alpha:]]+"," ",dvar); # turn any special character into space to make date parseable and protect against command injection
        cmd = "date -d \"" d"+10 days\" +%b/%d/%Y";
        cmd | getline expire; close(cmd);
        print " IP Address "$4 " Date Identified "$5 " Expiration " expire
      }
    ' FakeSip.txt
```

With credit due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630820/2858703), from which I've cribbed code for assigning command output to a variable:

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime
read -r x y z ip date time < FakeSip.txt &&
  LC_ALL=C strftime -rs t     '%b/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' "$date $time" &&
  LC_ALL=C strftime  -s expire %b/%d/%Y           $((t+10*24*60*60)) &&
  print -r IP Address $ip Date Identified $date Expiration $expire
```

The `LC_ALL=C` is to force those month abbreviations to be interpreted / output in English. Remove it so they be interpreted / output in the user's language instead.

Dates are interpreted in local time, we add 864000 seconds. That's not always the same as 10 days depending on how you define a *day* and where DST is involved.

Replace `$expire` with `${(L)expire}` (or `$expire:l` like in `tcsh`) for the month name to be converted to `L`ower case (`feb` instead of `Feb` to match the style of that `jan`).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I love datetime questions.

With perl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

# regex stolen from Regexp::Common::net
# https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net

my $re_ipv4 = qr/(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))/o;
my $fmt = '%b/%d/%Y';

while (<>) {
    my @F = split ' ';
    if ($F[3] =~ /^$re_ipv4$/) {
        my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($F[4], $fmt);
        my $exp = ($dt + 86400 * 10)->strftime($fmt);
        print "IP Address $F[3] Date Identified $F[4] Expiration " . lc($exp) . "\n";
    }
}
```

I'm not a huge fan of adding a number of seconds to represent days, but this code isn't timezone aware, so daylight saving transitions are not in play. To do this "properly", we'd need the [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) and [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime) modules from CPAN.

This results in

```
$ perl add10.pl file
IP Address 192.169.192.192 Date Identified jan/26/2022 Expiration feb/05/2022
```

Or ruby,

```ruby
require 'date'

re_ipv4 = Regexp.new("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))$")
fmt = '%b/%d/%Y'

File.new(ARGV.shift).each do |line|
  fields = line.split
  if fields[3].match?(re_ipv4)
    dt = Date.strptime(fields[4], fmt)
    exp = (dt + 10).strftime(fmt).downcase
    puts "IP Address #{fields[3]} Date Identified #{fields[4]} Expiration #{exp}"
  end
end
```

and

```
$ ruby add10.rb file
IP Address 192.169.192.192 Date Identified jan/26/2022 Expiration feb/05/2022
```